# Alpha channel through glass material instead of background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, transparency

I'm trying to render some windows, reflecting an environment map, and to be transparent to let light enter inside the house. There are two windows facing each, and I need to see through both, and keep the alpha channel here.

Here are the window's material nodes that do (half) the trick :

[image]

But, as you can see, there is no reflection on windows, which is needed. The *is Camera Ray* is overriding the reflections too. But if I don't add the *is Camera Ray* to the *is Shadow Ray*, the background is rendered instead of alpha channel:

[image]

Is there a way to have a "glass" material with reflections of an env map, light passing through and alpha channel through?

Comment: Well, thanks @RayMairlot, this should have answered, but only partially (see my edit).

Comment: @Polosson I realized that, and edited my answer with another solution which should answer both this question and the other, provided I understand correctly. Have you tried using a transparent shader?

Comment: Well, thanks @gandalf3, I tested your second solution with not much luck. And yes, I use a transparent shader, mixed with glass shader by a "light path" (as shown in the screenshots). The problem on your solution is that with the Fresnel node it doesn't work... May be an angle of camera view story... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Polosson Are your windows made of 2D planes? Try using the *Facing* output of the *Later Weight* node instead.

Comment: @gandalf3, no more luck with the *Facing* output of *Layer Weight*. The *blend* setting swaps from one situation to the other (reflexions and no alpha / no reflexions with alpha). I tried to play with *Light Path* to drive this *blend* setting, but no combination works.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that at shallow angles real windows will reflect almost all the light that hits them and goes into the camera. If you always want the window to be a mix of reflections and alpha, no need to plug anything into the factor input. Just set the mix factor directly.

Comment: @gandalf3 well, you're totally right, using manual mixing works fine. But, with a bit of tweaking I found that using the *Layer Weight* (with *Facing* output), and playing with the *blend* setting is more accurate in my case. Tell me if you want me to write an answer? Or, please do. Thanks a lot anyway!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

By mixing a glass or glossy shader with a transparent shader based on a fresnel node, rays will be allowed straight through the glass at smaller [angles of incidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_incidence), and will reflect at grazing angles. Rays which go through and reach the environment background will give alpha transparency:

[image]

Note that the Fresnel node is not necessary for mixing (setting the factor directly will get something like what you are looking for), but it does make the reflections of the material behave in a more physically based manner.