# Glass is white, independent the light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

hello i have this crystal, and is white rather transparent.Do you have any clues?

[image]

My final result,want to be like this:
[image]

now a changed my materials, i use two different materials,the first is the prism shader of eric adelo

[image]

and the second is a glossy material with texture:

[image]

here is the output

[image: 5]

Comment: Hi, could you please edit your question and use the post "add image" command to add the linked image? It would be permanent and much easier for everyone here to understand what you mean... thanks.

Comment: Maybe related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31888/alpha-channel-through-glass-material-instead-of-background-cycles. Node setup is required for questions like this and more description about what is your desired result.

Comment: Please post an image of your current material nodes.