# How do I export glass with the transparent background and Alpha channel (so I could see though it when compositing with another video)

Tags: transparency, glass

I'm trying to export a glass object in RGBA format. But the glass catches the HDRI colors in it and it's not transparent. And I wanted to use it to composite with another video so I need to be able to see through it.

Is there a setting that would turn that on/off?

Please see the example below:
[image]

Comment: In the _Render Properties_ under _Film_ > _Transparent_ you can find the option _Transparent Glass_ to enable.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann could you add that as an [answer to this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31888) please? That is a relevant new feature worth documenting, in an attempt to keep old questions relevant and up to date [following this discussion on meta](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2902). Feel free to add it here too for rep, and ping me in comments for upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

By default, blender does not have transparency in *GlassBSDF* node.
You have to use *TransparentBSDF* node to give transparent property to your material.

Here is my node setup for **Cycles engine**…
[image: my node setup for Cycles]

If you are using **EEVEE engine**. You have to change *Blend Mode* in material settings panel to *Alpha Hashed* or *Alpha Blend* (Alpha Hash will give some noise in renders. To render without noise, use Alpha Blend, but this would increase render time)

Here is my node setup for **EEVEE engine**…
[image: my node setup of EEVEE]

Finally, to remove HDRI effects, disconnect any texture nodes connected to *Background* node in *World Shader Node Editor*

*To reduce background effects on the object, decrease the strength value.

[image]